# How to create a newline on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, special-chars

I would like to know how to create a newline on the current android keyboard (for example in a sms).
And if it could be entered - would it be displayed?

**Edit:**
If you've got Android 4.1.

It is just below the delete button.

**Edit2 :**
For Android 2.X it still is the question, where to find it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what version of Android are you running? 2.3? 4.0+? What is your phone? Is it running a manufacturer keyboard or stock Android?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply press the `enter/return` button in your key board. It is located at the right botton corner of your keyboard.

In some cases, this button sends the SMS *(or submit applications, in cases of forms in websites)* If your device does that, simply hit enter/return button while holding the `shift  button` or the `upside arrow`

[image: lAYOUT]

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about single touch devices?

Comment: Good question. *As far as I know*, single touch devices does not face this problem. please try and let everybody know if you have one.

Comment: And what about Android 2.X devices? (I updated my question).

Comment: There is no `SHIFT` in GB? Please check again. There **IS**

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution. So I was facing the problem in WhatsApp and my new line button was replaced by the enter key,  so I went to the setting and I turned off the option " send messages with enter key" and voila, my new line button is here.

Comment: Yes I was looking for that, thank you +1

Comment: +1. Also was looking for that. I thought it is because of Android or Samsung keyboard. Couldn't even imagine that it can be in Whatsapp. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Press the shift key or the key to change letters from lovercase to uppercase and the Emoji button should change to a Return key.

Answer (score 0):

My dear friends,

this is an old question but there is still no answer, since I have connected 2 bluetooth keyboards to my Android smartphone running Shell Terminal Emulator
and none of the above, suggested solutions, entered a new line

I will try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo
since keyboard mappings can be edited and customized

My search for a ready solution, called: mapping MS Windows keyboard for use in Linux Shell failed to give results.

follow-up 1

I got it.
Installed another Shell Emulator
and Enter key started to work as Send + NewLine from bluetooth keyboard for iPad by Logitech, called Ultrathin Keyboard Cover.

Another, mini keyboard, supporting bluetooth, failed to work, mismatching the keys pressed vs. characters seen on display in Shell Terminal