# How to connect Bluetooth keyboard + bt mouse to Android smartphone to work in parallel?

Tags: terminal, external-keyboard

re.:
How to send carriage return + newline from Bluetooth keyboard connected to Android smartphone running shell emulator ?

followed answer links to similar questions
like
[How to create a newline on keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35564/how-to-create-a-newline-on-keyboard)

and

shift key + enter key pressed
just moves cursor in terminal mode one space to the right

on another, mini bluetoth keyboard, entering Fn + Esc did the new line trick, only once

Shift+Space opens the locked phone and Enter pressed, opens Shell Terminal Emulator

but another Enter press does nothing

upper left "Esc+ Enter pressed, escape Terminal, so Enter button works fine (new keyboard)

Not sure if External Keyboard Helper Demo could help me to test keyboard layout .

Comment: entering Fn + Space on a small bluetooth keyboard I can switch between opened application: Shell Terminal Emulator vs. Bluetooth settings

Comment: read question, comments and answer
Enter key is different from Carriage Return (CR)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349214/enter-key-is-different-from-carriage-return-cr

still not a solution but a good approach

Comment: first part solved, looking for a solution on how to connect multiple bluetooth devices to Android -
Windows XP came with such bluetooth software hub application/ drivers
to work with bluetooth mouse + bluetooth keyboard in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Another Shell Terminal application from Play store supports Enter key.
Only keyboard by Logitech is supported since ASCII keys input mismatch for mini keyboard